Find the declaration or location of an imported object via TypeScript API
I'm trying to write a script that uses the typescript compiler to modify imports in the code (I need to replace barrel imports with direct ones), but I'm not able to figure out the location or any other metadata of an imported object/function.
I have the following file structure:
| src/
|-- main.ts
|-- barrel/
|---- foo.ts
|---- index.ts

barrel/foo.ts:
export function foo(): void {
  console.log('foo()');
}

function defaultFoo(): void {
  console.log('defaultFoo()');
}

export default defaultFoo();

barrel/index.ts:
export * from './foo';

import { foo } from './barrel';

foo();

So I need to pick this { foo } import and figure out where exactly this function comes from.
I was able to get the associated ImportSpecifier but I'm not sure what to do next with this.
import ts from 'typescript';

function main(): void {
  const { config } = ts.readConfigFile(
    'PATH',
    ts.sys.readFile
  );

  const { options, fileNames, errors } = ts.parseJsonConfigFileContent(config, ts.sys, 'PATH');
  const program = ts.createProgram({ options, rootNames: fileNames, configFileParsingDiagnostics: errors });

  const sampleFile = program.getSourceFiles().find(f => f.fileName.endsWith('main.ts'));
  sampleFile.forEachChild(node => {
    if (ts.isImportDeclaration(node)){
      node.importClause.forEachChild(namedImport => {
        if (ts.isNamedImports(namedImport)) {
          // I'm here, what's next?
        }
      })
    }
  });
}

main();


